# Windows Server Active Directory API

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, api

I need to develop a web application that must show a user's directory in Windows Server Active Directory.

Does Windows Server Active Directory have some API that I can call to retrive those informations?

Comment: it certainly does, have a look at [Azure AD Graph REST API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974478.aspx) and [System.DirectoryServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DirectoryServices(v=vs.100).aspx) for C#/VB.net

Comment: Can I use it directly from javascript/jquery?

Comment: You can using the REST API, what operation you need (list all users, search for a user by name, ... etc)?

Comment: I will need to link/map an user logged on my web app to an user in Active Directory first. That user will see his file system "tree" (i.e. the first level), and it will be able to navigate through it by clicking on folders. Next he will need to retrive a file.

Comment: for example the list of folders and file. Myabe you're right, now that I know that there are some APIs I can go with a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

## WSH:

```
' ADSI Constant declarations

const ADS_GROUP_TYPE_GLOBAL_GROUP = &h2
const ADS_GROUP_TYPE_LOCAL_GROUP = &h4
const ADS_GROUP_TYPE_UNIVERSAL_GROUP = &h8
const ADS_GROUP_TYPE_SECURITY_ENABLED = &h80000000

Const ADS_PROPERTY_CLEAR = 1
Const ADS_PROPERTY_UPDATE = 2
Const ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND = 3
Const ADS_PROPERTY_DELETE = 4

'#region ADSIUser Class
Class ADSIUser

Public ADUser

Public Function GetItem(strItem)
    
        GetItem = ADUser.Get(strItem)

End Function

Public Function GetItemEx(strItem)
    
        GetItemEx = ADUser.GetEx(strItem)

End Function

Public Sub PutItem(strItem,newValue)

        ADUser.Put strItem, newValue
        ADUser.SetInfo

End Sub

Public Sub PutItemEx(strItem, newValueArray)

        ADUser.PutEx ADS_PROPERTY_UPDATE, strItem, newValueArray
        ADUser.SetInfo
        
End Sub

Public Sub ClearItem(strItem)

        ADUser.PutEx ADS_PROPERTY_CLEAR, strItem, 0
        ADUser.SetInfo

End Sub

Public Sub AppendItem(strItem, newValueArray)

        ADUser.PutEx ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND, strItem, newValueArray
        ADUser.SetInfo

End Sub

Public Sub PrintItems

        On Error Resume Next

        WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** General Properties Page**"
        WScript.Echo "** (Single-Valued Attributes) **"
        WScript.Echo "name: " & ADUser.Get("name")
        WScript.Echo "givenName: " & ADUser.Get("givenName")
        WScript.Echo "initials: " & ADUser.Get("initials")
        WScript.Echo "sn: " & ADUser.Get("sn")
        WScript.Echo "displayName: " & ADUser.Get("displayName")
        WScript.Echo "description: " & ADUser.Get("description")
        WScript.Echo "physicalDeliveryOfficeName: " & ADUser.Get("physicalDeliveryOfficeName")
    WScript.Echo "telephoneNumber: " & ADUser.Get("telephoneNumber")
    WScript.Echo "mail: " & ADUser.Get("mail")
    WScript.Echo "wWWHomePage: " & ADUser.Get("wWWHomePage")
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** General Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (MultiValued Attributes) **"
    WScript.Echo "otherTelephone:"
    For Each Item in ADUser.GetEx("otherTelephone")
     WScript.Echo vbTab & Item
    Next
    WScript.Echo "url:"
    For Each Item in ADUser.GetEx("url")
     WScript.Echo vbTab & Item
    Next
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Address Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (Single-Valued Attributes) **"
    WScript.Echo "streetAddress: " & ADUser.Get("streetAddress")
    WScript.Echo "l: " & ADUser.Get("l")
    WScript.Echo "st: " & ADUser.Get("st")
    WScript.Echo "postalCode: " & ADUser.Get("postalCode")
    WScript.Echo "c: " & ADUser.Get("c")
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Address Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (MultiValued Attributes) **"
    WScript.Echo "postOfficeBox:"
    For Each Item in ADUser.GetEx("postOfficeBox")
     WScript.Echo vbTab & Item
    Next
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Account Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (Single-Valued Attributes) **"
    WScript.Echo "userPrincipalName: " & ADUser.Get("userPrincipalName")
    WScript.Echo "dc: " & ADUser.Get("dc")
    WScript.Echo "sAMAccountName: " & ADUser.Get("sAMAccountName")
    WScript.Echo "userWorkstations: " & ADUser.Get("userWorkstations")
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Account Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (The userAccountControl attribute) **"
    Set objHash = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    objHash.Add "ADS_UF_SMARTCARD_REQUIRED", &h40000
    objHash.Add "ADS_UF_TRUSTED_FOR_DELEGATION", &h80000
    objHash.Add "ADS_UF_NOT_DELEGATED", &h100000
    objHash.Add "ADS_UF_USE_DES_KEY_ONLY", &h200000
    objHash.Add "ADS_UF_DONT_REQUIRE_PREAUTH", &h400000
    intuserAccountControl = ADUser.Get("userAccountControl")
    For Each Key in objHash.Keys
      If objHash(Key) And intuserAccountControl Then
        WScript.Echo Key & " is enabled."
      Else
        WScript.Echo Key & " is disabled."
      End If
    Next
    If ADUser.IsAccountLocked = True Then
      WScript.Echo "ADS_UF_LOCKOUT is enabled"
    Else
      WScript.Echo "ADS_UF_LOCKOUT is disabled"
    End If
    
    If err.Number = -2147467259 Or ADUser.AccountExpirationDate = "1/1/1970" Then
      WScript.Echo "Account doesn't expire."
    Else
      WScript.Echo "Account expires on: " & ADUser.AccountExpirationDate
    End If
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Profile Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (Single-Valued Attributes) **"
    WScript.Echo "profilePath: " & ADUser.Get("profilePath")
    WScript.Echo "scriptPath: " & ADUser.Get("scriptPath")
    WScript.Echo "homeDirectory: " & ADUser.Get("homeDirectory")
    WScript.Echo "homeDrive: " & ADUser.Get("homeDrive")
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Telephone Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (Single-Valued Attributes) **"
    WScript.Echo "homePhone: " & ADUser.Get("homePhone")
    WScript.Echo "pager: " & ADUser.Get("pager")
    WScript.Echo "mobile: " & ADUser.Get("mobile")
    WScript.Echo "facsimileTelephoneNumber: " & ADUser.Get("facsimileTelephoneNumber")
    WScript.Echo "ipPhone: " & ADUser.Get("ipPhone")
    WScript.Echo "info: " & ADUser.Get("info")
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Telephone Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (MultiValued Attributes) **"
    WScript.Echo "otherHomePhone:"
    For Each Item in ADUser.GetEx("otherHomePhone")
     WScript.Echo vbTab & Item
    Next
    WScript.Echo "otherPager:"
    For Each Item in ADUser.GetEx("otherPager")
     WScript.Echo vbTab & Item
    Next
    WScript.Echo "otherMobile:"
    For Each Item in ADUser.GetEx("otherMobile")
     WScript.Echo vbTab & Item
    Next
    WScript.Echo "otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber:"
    For Each Item in ADUser.GetEx("otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber")
     WScript.Echo vbTab & Item
    Next
    WScript.Echo "otherIpPhone:"
    For Each Item in ADUser.GetEx("otherIpPhone")
     WScript.Echo vbTab & Item
    Next
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Organization Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (Single-Valued Attributes) **"
    WScript.Echo "title: " & ADUser.Get("title")
    WScript.Echo "department: " & ADUser.Get("department")
    WScript.Echo "company: " & ADUser.Get("company")
    WScript.Echo "manager: " & ADUser.Get("manager")
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Organization Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (MultiValued Attributes) **"
    WScript.Echo "directReports:"
    For Each Item in ADUser.GetEx("directReports")
     WScript.Echo vbTab & Item
    Next
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Environment Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (The ADSI Extension for Terminal Services interface) **"
    WScript.Echo "TerminalServicesInitialProgram: " & ADUser.TerminalServicesInitialProgram
    WScript.Echo "TerminalServicesWorkDirectory: " & ADUser.TerminalServicesWorkDirectory
    WScript.Echo "ConnectClientDrivesAtLogon: " & ADUser.ConnectClientDrivesAtLogon
    WScript.Echo "ConnectClientPrintersAtLogon: " & ADUser.ConnectClientPrintersAtLogon
    WScript.Echo "DefaultToMainPrinter: " & ADUser.DefaultToMainPrinter
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Sessions Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (The ADSI Extension for Terminal Services interface) **"
    WScript.Echo "MaxDisconnectionTime: " & ADUser.MaxDisconnectionTime
    WScript.Echo "MaxConnectionTime: " & ADUser.MaxConnectionTime
    WScript.Echo "MaxIdleTime: " & ADUser.MaxIdleTime
    WScript.Echo "BrokenConnectionAction: " & ADUser.BrokenConnectionAction
    WScript.Echo "ReconnectionAction: " & ADUser.ReconnectionAction
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Remote Control Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (The ADSI Extension for Terminal Services interface) **"
    WScript.Echo "EnableRemoteControl: " & ADUser.EnableRemoteControl
    
    Select Case ADUser.EnableRemoteControl
      Case 0
        WScript.Echo "Remote Control disabled"
      Case 1
        WScript.Echo "Remote Control enabled"
        WScript.Echo "User permission required"
        WScript.Echo "Interact with the session"
      Case 2
        WScript.Echo "Remote Control enabled"
        WScript.Echo "User permission not required"
        WScript.Echo "Interact with the session"
      Case 3
        WScript.Echo "Remote Control enabled"
        WScript.Echo "User permission required"
        WScript.Echo "View the session"
      Case 4
        WScript.Echo "Remote Control enabled"
        WScript.Echo "User permission not required"
        WScript.Echo "View the session"
    End Select
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Terminal Services Profile Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (The ADSI Extension for Terminal Services interface) **"
    WScript.Echo "TerminalServicesProfilePath: " & ADUser.TerminalServicesProfilePath
    WScript.Echo "TerminalServicesHomeDirectory: " & ADUser.TerminalServicesHomeDirectory
    WScript.Echo "TerminalServicesHomeDrive: " & ADUser.TerminalServicesHomeDrive
    WScript.Echo "AllowLogon: " & ADUser.AllowLogon
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** COM+ Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (Single-Valued Attributes) **"
    WScript.Echo "msCOM-UserPartitionSetLink: " & ADUser.Get("msCOM-UserPartitionSetLink")
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Member Of Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (Single-Valued Attributes) **"
    WScript.Echo "primaryGroupID: " & ADUser.Get("primaryGroupID")
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Member Of Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (MultiValued Attributes) **"
    WScript.Echo "memberOf:"
    For Each Item in ADUser.GetEx("memberOf")
     WScript.Echo vbTab & Item
    Next
    
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Object Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (Single-Valued Attributes) **"
    WScript.Echo "whenCreated: " & ADUser.Get("whenCreated")
    WScript.Echo "whenChanged: " & ADUser.Get("whenChanged")
    
    ADUser.GetInfoEx Array("canonicalName"), 0
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "** Object Properties Page**"
    WScript.Echo "** (MultiValued Attributes) **"
    WScript.Echo "canonicalName:"
    For Each Item in ADUser.GetEx("canonicalName")
     WScript.Echo vbTab & Item
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

End Class

'#endregion

'#region ADSIConnection Class
Class ADSIConnection

        Private ADSIRootObject
        Private Initialized

Private Sub ConnectToRoot()

        If Initialized = 0 Then
                Set ADSIRootObject = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")
                Initialized = 1
        End If
End Sub

Private Function ConnectToContainer(strContainer,strName)

        Dim ADSIContainer
        Dim Root
        Dim objItem
        
        ConnectToRoot
        If strContainer = "" Then
                Set objItem = GetObject("LDAP://" & ADSIRootObject.Get("defaultNamingContext"))
        Else
                If strName = "" Then
                                Set objItem = GetObject("LDAP://" & strContainer & "," & ADSIRootObject.Get("defaultNamingContext"))
                Else
                                Set objItem = GetObject("LDAP://cn=" & strName & "," & strContainer & "," & ADSIRootObject.Get("defaultNamingContext"))
                End If
        End If
        Set ConnectToContainer = objItem
End Function

Public Sub CreateUser(strContainer,strName)

        Dim objUser
        Dim ADSIContainer
        
        Set ADSIContainer = ConnectToContainer(strContainer,"")
        Set objUser = ADSIContainer.Create("user", "cn=" & strName)
        objUser.Put "SAMAccountName", strName
        objUser.SetInfo
End Sub

Public Sub DeleteUser(strContainer,strName)

        Dim ADSIContainer

        Set ADSIContainer = ConnectToContainer(strContainer,"")
        ADSIContainer.Delete "user", "cn=" & strName
        
End Sub

Public Function GetUser(objUser,strContainer,strName)

        Set objUser.ADUser = ConnectToContainer(strContainer,strName)
        GetUser = True

End Function    

End Class
'#endregion

' Sample ADSI Wizard code

Dim objADSI
Dim objADSIUser

Set objADSI = New ADSIConnection
Set objADSIUser = New ADSIUser

if False Then
        ' Additional Wizard Sample Code
        Call objADSI.GetUser(objADSIUser,"cn=Users","Hooten")
        objADSI.CreateUser "cn=Users","Hooten"
End If
```